# How to Find out two Highest values from different Columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have various types of marks in my `student_marks` table, let say `Quiz1`, `Quiz2`, `Quiz3`, `First_Monthly` ,`Second_Monthly`, `Third_monthly`.

I Have created a trigger which calculates all the marks and add the sum in `Final_Marks` field.

I don't want `Final_marks` field to add all the columns and sum them, I want to select only the top 2 `Quiz_Marks` and Top2 `Monthly_Marks` and add their sum in `FinalMarks`.

I searched on net and found the `greatest` keyword that selects the Highest Column value from table , but here i don't want a single value, I need at least 2 Highest values against every ID.

-

**Trigger[Right now its adding all the columns]**

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.FinalMarks = NEW.AssignmentMarks + NEW.QuizMarks
                       + NEW.Hourly1 + NEW.Hourly2 + NEW.Hourly3 
                       + NEW.ProjectMarks,
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Normalise your design

Comment: +1 Excuse me while I eat my words

Comment: Isn't it normalized? If i further divide `student_marks` table then it might be difficult to update `final_marks` column , each time a user update marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have five values. To get the greatest, you use GREATEST (of course). To get the second greatest, you do the following: Find the greatest for each tuple of only four values. There are five tuples of course, one with element 1 missing, one with element 2 missing, etc. So you get four times the greatest value of all five and one time the second greatest value. Use least to get that second greatest value. That's it.

```
SET NEW.FinalMarks =
GREATEST(new.quizmarks, new.hourly1, new.hourly2, new.hourly3, new.projectmarks)
+
LEAST
(
  GREATEST(new.quizmarks, new.hourly1, new.hourly2, new.hourly3),
  GREATEST(new.quizmarks, new.hourly1, new.hourly2, new.projectmarks),
  GREATEST(new.quizmarks, new.hourly1, new.hourly3, new.projectmarks),
  GREATEST(new.quizmarks, new.hourly2, new.hourly3, new.projectmarks),
  GREATEST(new.hourly1, new.hourly2, new.hourly3, new.projectmarks),
)
```

Modify this, so it meets your request to treat Quiz_Marks and Monthly_Marks separately.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question here's the solution for your problem, use this code (this code is for undestanding you may modify it a little bit to fits the data you want to treat :

```
DECLARE  @v_type1 INT = 0
        ,@v_type2 INT = 0
            ,@v_type3 INT = 0;

WITH temp AS (
select 1 typeid, 12 note union all
select 1 typeid, 11 note union all
select 1 typeid, 13 note union all
select 2 typeid, 18 note union all
select 2 typeid, 19 note union all
select 2 typeid, 19 note union all
select 3 typeid, 21 note)


select
         @v_type1 = @v_type1
                    +ISNULL(CASE WHEN typeid = 1 AND ROW_NUMBER()     over (partition by typeid ORDER BY note DESC)<=2
                        THEN note
                        ELSE 0
                    END,0)
        ,@v_type2 = @v_type2
                    +ISNULL(CASE WHEN typeid = 2 AND ROW_NUMBER()     over (partition by typeid ORDER BY note DESC)<=2
                        THEN note
                        ELSE 0
                    END,0)
        ,@v_type3 = @v_type3
                    +ISNULL(CASE WHEN typeid = 3 AND ROW_NUMBER()     over (partition by typeid ORDER BY note DESC)<=2
                        THEN note
                        ELSE 0
                        END,0)
    from temp


    SELECT @v_type1,@v_type2,@v_type3
```

I hope this will help you,
Good Luck